# How to get 100% of cpu time from vspere api

Tags: vsphere, esxi

I`m getting host performance metrics from vShere 5.1 API, using "realtime" interval(20 seconds). I want to understand how i can get percentage what CPU is doing, during this interval.
I can get this metrics:

- **idle**
- **wait**
- **swap wait**
- **co-stop**
- **ready**
- **used**

Metrics unit is millisecond, but values are much bigger then possible count of milliseconds during time interval(20000 ms). Also metrics values are "delta"(current - previous value).
And one more detail: on several hosts **idle** value was greate then wait, but [docs](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc%2Fcpu_counters.html) says that **idle** included into **wait**

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the *usage* metric; this reports a percent number.  It reports this similar to load average result.  So, if you have a four CPU host (it's just for easy example) and a VM is consuming 50% of the host CPU then two of those cores are maxed in theory.

Comment: I`m not interested in VM stats, only in Host stats. Also i need map of CPU usage^ how long HOST CPU was in idle, was waiting,  and etc. Not just avarage percentage usage

Comment: With PowerCLI that is not too difficult; you could do something like

$vmHost = Get-VMHost MyHost
$vmHost.CpuUsageMhz

This is an example, explore all the properties of vmHost to see if what you want is in there, odds are it is.  You can also use Get-ESXTop to get some very detailed stats from the host.